# Simplify replace with regex

Tags: .net, regex

How can I replace this rather clumsy code with a regex?

```
Dim InvoiceNumber As String = filename.Split("_")(1).Replace("-00", "/").Replace("-0", "/0").Replace("-", "/")
```

Examples of the filenames to be processed:

```
617809_53070664_EB867_20170710
617809_53069537_308CB588_20170710
617809_53069392_307RS0635_20170710
617809_53060543-001_307RS0630_20170710
```

I need to get:

```
53070664
53069537
53069392
53060543/1
```

Comment: If the code works fine, it might be a better idea to post it at [codereview.se] to ask for enhancements. Note a regex solution won't look neat because you need to check for a condition when replacing (you will need a match evaluator).

Comment: How about `/_(.*?)_/g`

Comment: @NullDev It won't help. Post-edition with `Replace` methods will be still necessary.

Comment: IMHO any Regex that would do all of the splitting and replacing would look way more clumsy. The way you have it now is clear, and kind of obviously says how you are manipulating the input string. Using regex for this will strip you out of this. Also, as @WiktorStribiżew mentioned - you might want to check the code review for further improvements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this approach ( [run the sample](http://ideone.com/royyiK) )

```
  string pattern = @"\d+_(\d+)(?:-0{0,}(\d+))?_.*";
        string input = @"617809_53070664_EB867_20170710
617809_53069537_308CB588_20170710
617809_53069392_307RS0635_20170710
617809_53060543-001_307RS0630_20170710
";

            foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
            {
                if(m.Groups[2].Value!="")
                 Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]+"/"+m.Groups[2]);
                else
                 Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This does the trick but I will be sticking with the original code for intelligibility reasons.